# Capture python output to variable

Tags: python, web-scraping

I'm trying to automate [pybaseball](https://github.com/jldbc/pybaseball) from player lookup to data extraction and can't seem to get past the first step of setting the player id as a variable.

I'm utilizing the following code to pull player id:

```
from pybaseball import playerid_lookup

data = playerid_lookup("kershaw", "clayton", fuzzy=True)
```

The output from the above lines are (exact copy/paste):

```
  name_last name_first  key_mlbam key_retro  key_bbref  key_fangraphs  mlb_played_first  mlb_played_last
0   kershaw    clayton     477132  kersc001  kershcl01           2036            2008.0           2022.0
```

Is there a method for setting the key_fangraphs number (2036) to a variable from this output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the `pybaseball.playerid_lookup.playerid_lookup()` method returns a `pandas.DataFrame`, you should be able to use the `pandas.DataFrame.get()` method. Something like `data.get("key_fangraphs", default=-1)`. It would return -1 if there was no "key_fangraphs" column.

Comment: That's what I was looking for, thanks! For anyone else that finds this I utilized .to_string(index=False) to remove the row index and output just the data.